# BigQuery join table after case statement in subquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to write a query that can be run weekly or monthly that with some numerical changes that can be done in google sheets. For this to work however, I need to change some product names so that they are more uniform and in line with the data from the google sheets. In this case something like senior or junior in front of the product name should all become one specific name like 'Engineer' instead of senior engineer, engineer, junior engineer etc. However, it gives an error on the join like it's not allowing the from clause following it.

The short summary code of how I am trying to do that is this (group by etc has been left out):

```
SELECT 
      t.fullVisitorId,
      t.product,
      t.transaction,
      t.transactiondate,
      cc.productvalue   
FROM t LEFT JOIN
`othertable` AS cc ON t.product = cc.product    
FROM(
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN product = '%engineer%' THEN 'Engineer'
END AS product,
fullVisitorId,
transaction,
value,
transactiondate
    FROM ( SELECT
     fullVisitorId,
              hit.transaction.transactionId AS transaction,
              prod.v2ProductName AS product,
           FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(SAFE_CAST(visitStartTime AS INT64)), "Europe/London") AS transactiondate
            FROM
          `tableID.ga_sessions_*` AS t
        CROSS JOIN
          UNNEST(hits) AS hit            
        WHERE
          _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', '2018-11-01') 
          AND FORMAT_DATE("%E4Y%m%d", '2018-11-30')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT 
  t.fullVisitorId,
  t.product,
  t.transaction,
  t.transactiondate,
  cc.productvalue   
FROM (
  SELECT CASE WHEN product LIKE '%engineer%' THEN 'Engineer' END AS product,
    fullVisitorId,
    transaction,
    value,
    transactiondate
  FROM ( 
    SELECT
      fullVisitorId,
      hit.transaction.transactionId AS transaction,
      prod.v2ProductName AS product,
      FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(SAFE_CAST(visitStartTime AS INT64)), "Europe/London") AS transactiondate
    FROM `tableID.ga_sessions_*` AS t
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hit            
    WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', '2018-11-01') 
    AND FORMAT_DATE("%E4Y%m%d", '2018-11-30')
  )
) AS t
LEFT JOIN `othertable` AS cc 
ON t.product = cc.product
```

Also, note `product LIKE '%engineer%'` instead of `product = '%engineer%'`